# Use leaflet-draw-toolbar with angular 2

Tags: leaflet, toolbar, leaflet-draw, angular2

Is it possible to use leaflet-draw-toolbar with angular 2 and ngx-leaflet-draw?

I do not see, and I am not versed in Angular 2, enough, to incorporate the JS library for leaflet-draw-toolbar into my code.